# How can I use rfcomm to connect to multiple android smartphones to my Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi3, rfcomm, pybluez

I am trying to connect my Raspberry Pi 3 to three android phones through Bluetooth. I want to use the input of the phones in a python code, but before I start coding I have to make sure I can connect all three phones to the Raspberry Pi 3.

The following stuff I did was:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
sudo rpi-update

sudo apt-get install python3
sudo apt-get install python-bluetooth

sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/dbus-org.bluez.service
```

Changed the next two lines:

```
ExecStart=/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd -C
ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/sdptool add SP
```

I am using the BlueTooth Serial Conntroller app on the smartphones.
Next I connect through `sudo rfcomm listen hci0` which works fine.

I check the connection with `minicom -D /dev/rfcomm0` and that works as well. I can send commando's with the app and it shows on the terminal on my Raspberry Pi.

Next, while that connection is active, I try to connect the second phone with `sudo rfcomm listen hci2` which connects for a moment on the phone, but on the screen it quickly gives me the message

> Can't create rfcomm TTY: address already in use

So I'm thinking it's because I'm using channel 1. So I try `sudo rfcomm listen hci2 2` which displays it's waiting on channel 2. But that doesn't work either.

I have checked if I can connect to the second phone on the first channel (when it's free) and it works.

So my question is:
How can I use rfcomm to connect to multiple android smartphones?
Or is there another better way knowing that I want to use Python to use the input?

Answer (score 2):

I had this same exact problem, and this is how I solved it: `sudo rfcomm listen /dev/rfcommX 1` where X starts at 0 and increments by 1 for every device you want to connect.